# Error 404 for while connecting Axios to an endpoint Login

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, cors

In the following code, I am retrieving data from user via a login page.

The data then has to be passed to an API. I wasn't able to pass it to the API.

```js
document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('submit', async(event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const username = document.getElementById('Username').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('Password').value;
  const formData = JSON.stringify({
    "username": username,
    "password": password
   });
  let config = {
    method: 'POST',
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/Login',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    data: formData
  };
  try {
    console.log("abc")
    const response = await axios.request(config);
    console.log(response.data);
    alert('Successfully Logged In');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(err.response);
    alert(err.message);
  }
});
```

I wanted to call my endpoint Login with the help of the above code. I wasn't able to due to the above mentioned error any changes that I must do so that I rectify the above error.

Comment: What console log shows? Have you checked in the network tab? 404 tells us that api doesn't exist. Check your backend. Try with postman.

Comment: M {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
: 
"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config
this is the error im getting

Comment: Show us your backend.

Comment: FYI, you can use shorthand: `const formData = JSON.stringify({ username, password });`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use await, it should be inside an async function. But there can be problems with your api too.

Comment: Top level await is possible now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).